# Submit value on GET

Tags: php, html

OK, this is probably elementary, but I'm having a mental block.

I have a set of radio buttons and I need to submit the value to a URL in the following format:

```
mypage/myValue
```

and not

```
mypage/?name=myValue
```

Here's what I have:

```
<form action="mypage/" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="myValue_1"> label 1
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="myValue_2"> label 2
    <input type="radio" name="name" value="myValue_3"> label 3
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Perhaps I'm overthinking but my initial reaction is to form the URL with jQuery on click, and than just redirect... Sounds a bit too much, isn't it?

Comment: Either use javascript to build that url on submit or redirect server side

Comment: You cam send the request by javascript and then maintain it by .htaccess or once the form submitted redirect it by php, but in both cases you need a .htacceess files

Comment: Why not simply use a set of links for this if all you desire is to link to different urls? Then theme it to your liking.

Comment: @sfyn, links will be easy, but this is what client wants.

Comment: @PeeHaa glad to see some confirmation of my initial thinking.

Comment: FWIW I would totally go for the serverside redirect

Comment: If you must process via php then you can use the [header()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to redirect to the url of your choice.

Comment: It's a template file, seems like jQuery will be a lot easier.

Comment: @santa: Using `.htaccess` would be easier. Something like this should work: `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/?$ example.com/?name=$1 [L,QSA]`.

Comment: Don't have access to .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't be mush code (jQuery) if it's only the radios - something like:

```
<form>
    <input type="radio" name="rname" value="myValue_1"> label 1
    <input type="radio" name="rname" value="myValue_2"> label 2
    <input type="radio" name="rname" value="myValue_3"> label 3
    <input type="button" id="btncl">
</form>
```

and in the script:

```
$("#btncl").click(function(){
  window.location="mypage/"+$('input[name=rname]:radio:checked').val();
});
```

Otherwise, I don't think there is a way of doing it with regular html, since the standards say that GET is ...?name=val&n2=v2....

The server side redirection should be more time-consuming (for both writing and using)